# why is phantomjs not displaying icons correctly?

Tags: macos, phantomjs

two of my team members are running the same script with phantomjs, but get different results. The script is:

```
var url = 'http://10.10.1.10/#/blueprints';

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 800
};

page.open(url, function() {
  page.render('screenshot.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

- Different machines
- Pointing to same host 10.10.1.10
- One is on ubuntu 14, the other on mac (on mac icons are wrong)
- phantomjs version is 1.9.8 for both of them

The result is different. One is showing the icons properly, the other does not.

What is going on? How can we debug/solve this problem?

[image: The result is different]

Comment: aha... finally (after 2 days of searching), I found it.. always happens right after I publish an SO question :( https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12132

Comment: the question is still unresolved though

Comment: ok so downgrading to 1.9.1 solves the issue. http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount. if someone will answer this in the next couple of days I will mark their answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems to be a phantomjs issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12132).

so downgrading to [1.9.1](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) solves the issue.

hopefully this will be resolved in 2.x